# Conditional response in a map chained to a filter that may return an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I have filter and map function chained. I need to do something conditional on whether a filter returns an empty array or not. However the map function on the array does not seem to be invoked if the filter returns an empty array.

```
const letters = ["a", "b", "c"];
const numbers = [1, 2, 3]

function result (arr) {

arr.filter((x) => {return x === "a"}).map((y, i, arr) => {

if(arr.length === 0) {
return //do something
} else {
return //do something else
}})
}
```

Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?

I was expecting the filter result to be passed to the map function, which can be used as the 3rd argument of the map function: map(item, index, array)

Here's a JSFiddle of the problem
https://jsfiddle.net/sub3z0xh/

Comment: You shouldn't be using `map()` for outside side-effects anyway. For your use case it looks like you're actually looking for [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which returns a boolean if any elements of the array satisfy the condition. `document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = arr.some(e => e === 'a') ? 'found it' : 'empty';
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Comment: @pilchard, thanks for the suggestion. In my real case there's something more complicated going on inside the Map, I just used a simple and misleading example.

Comment: Hmm, any external side effects in a `map()` call is an anti-pattern though, as is not assigning the result to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re right about what’s happening. Array methods run once per element in the source array. If the source array is empty, it doesn’t run.

This isn’t new or working different with array methods vs a basic for loop. Example:

```
const arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(“this code never runs because there are no elements to loop”);
}
```

So maybe just store the result of the filter in a variable instead. Get rid of the chained map since it may not run. Check the size/contents of your filtered array, then do stuff with that.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. That makes sense. I guess I can do what I need by not chaining the functions, and instead assign the filter result to a variable and assess that for zero length.

Much appreciated ceckenrode!